# Best practice on unused SQL data

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have database where I give user a message and user can delete that message. There could be potentially thousands of queries per second for this table.

I have read that `DELETE` statements are slower than `UPDATE`, should I take this into consideration? I already have a `deleted` column so I can know If the message is "deleted". However, should I perform a `DELETE` statement immediately or should I delete all read messages nightly or with similar approach?

`UPDATE` statement should be faster, but then I'm left with bunch of data that has to be deleted later on so the size of database does not grow too large

`DELETE` statement should be more "logical", but can there be performance issues with too many `DELETE` queries?

Can there be problems with approach where I delete everything at once, could it hang the database?

Comment: Delete and update are two different things, and they might not even be interchangeable for what you are trying to do.  Your current approach of marking a record as ready for deletion is usually called "soft deletion."  And yes, one common approach would be to run a batch job every day which goes in and removes such records.

Comment: "then I'm left with bunch of data that has to be deleted later on so the size of database does not grow too large" ..."too large" is subjective according to your hardware, indexes, usage of table etc. You'd have to find a threshold where performance of any of the various types queries you run on this table actually starts to degrade, if ever. Plus are you assuming you don't need to keep the records for a long period for audit or history purposes? In that scenario, a "soft" delete by using an UPDATE to set a Deleted field is the right approach.

Comment: How many records, how many users, how many "deletes" compared to "reads" per minute?

Comment: ADyson, "too large" meaning increased costs for both the database and backups. We're doing online games so it is extremely important that the backend systems scale indefinitely from the start.

Comment: In addition to Tim Biegeleisen's suggestion above, if you choose to physically delete your "soft deletes" at a later stage. Do them in smaller batches rather than trying to delete everything at one time. This will help with manageable transactions sizes and not be too big of a drag on performance.

Comment: This really is too vague and too broad. From the description of your process you are making design decisions based on a performance issue that does not exist. This is known as premature optimization and it is the spawn of the devil. When you actually have a performance issue then you may need to look closely at your process and adjust to fit. And since we don't know the schema of your database, the size of the tables or really what you are doing this is just impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure "delete is slower than update" is true in all (or even most) circumstances - there are lots of different things that affect performance.

Secondly, optimizing for performance requires lots of interrelated trade-offs - this is a very "micro" decision, and it may not have any impact at all. Or it may move the performance challenge to a different part of the stack, or a different moment in time.

Thirdly, this tends to be a "hockey stick" question - in my experience, database performance is absolutely fine all the way until it rapidly deteriorates, and until you know the cause of that deterioration, you may well be wasting time or introducing additional complexity for little reward.

In general terms, `delete from messages where id = $1` will be as fast as `update messages set deleted = 1 where id = $1`. However, if you are using a clustered index on the primary key for this table, you may end up with lots of index "gaps", and rebuilding the index can be expensive. This affects both your "delete in real time", or "soft delete followed by batch deletes" strategy.

I would recommend you build a performance test environment, and load it up with lots of dummy data; you can then script performance tests to see what the actual problems are.